# How to read values in __NSDictionaryI swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift3, nsdictionary

I am trying to convert json string to class object. this is class

```
    class UserChallengeResponse : NSObject{
    var key : String?
    var questions : [ChallengeQuestion] = []

 init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard let key = json[PropertyKey.key] as? String ,
            [ChallengeQuestion] else { return nil }
            let questions = json[PropertyKey.questions] else { return nil }        
        self.key = key
        self.questions = questions as! [ChallengeQuestion]       
    }
}
```

This is how I pass json object

```
userChallegeResp = UserChallengeResponse(json: ref.responseObject!)!
let questions:[ChallengeQuestion] = self.userChallegeResp.questions
```

in Debug I can see the values like this.
[image]

when I try to access value like this

```
questions[1]
```

throws error " NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"

How do I access this questions array ?

Comment: how do I move to 0 index to read questions["primary"] ? is there any way to direct cast json object to class like gson in java?

Comment: No in image you can see 1 index. and also top of the image 2 values. no matter for 0 index same error

Comment: I see no index `1` for any array on the screenshot, what you see index `[1]` that is totally different thing, the dictionaries' keys are assorted and not indexed at all... the actual value seems more likely a `let question = dict["question"] as? String` to me, no array has been parsed here for that _key_.

Comment: You have told Swift that `questions` is an array of `ChallengeQuestion` but is an array of `[String:Any]`.

Comment: I mean array of this var questions : [ChallengeQuestion] = []

Comment: @Thushara, and could you please point out where that mysterious array is, please...? because I see dictionaries only, but there is a chance of you might have not shared every details in your post yet, perhaps? the dictionaries work with _key-value_ pairs not by indices.

Comment: this is the array
questions:[ChallengeQuestion] = self.userChallegeResp.questions

Comment: you need to write code to convert the array of dictionaries that you get in the JSON response into your ChallengeQuestion objects. At th smoke test you are simply assigning the array of dictionary to an array and you get a runtime error because the array doesn’t contain the type of object that you told Swift it would.

Comment: can you please send me sample code relevant to this. json response cast to class object contains array of object

Answer (score 0):

Usually done so:

```
    guard let responseData = data
        else {
            print("parse tokens failed")
            return
    }

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let tokens = Tokens(JSON: json) {
                self.tokens = tokens
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("json error: \(error)")
    }
    self.isFinished = true
}
```

Your mistake is that You are doing the right Customization of the data obtained.